# Android Notification Update for same notification id

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I am using the same notification id to show the notification of my app. 
I am passing an object with the intent to launch the activity.
The issue is for same notification id, android caches the initial object which is passed along the intent.

So how can I make sure that the latest object is added in the intent.

Or how can I check if a notification with the id is not cleared in the notification panel and if it's there then I can delete the notification and create a new one.

Note :- I want to avoid the scenario to use new notification id as that keeps creating new notification without removing the older ones.

Comment: why dont you just cancel it and start a new one, if its not there, nothing will take effect.

Answer (score 3):

Use PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT in your Pending Intent like below

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    NotificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Answer (score 1):

call `notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);` before calling `notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());`