# Notification Update onPostExecute AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, notifications

```
<-- Android/Java --->

private NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
private NotificationCompat.Builder build;
final int id = 101;

private class Download extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();

         // Displays the progress bar for the first time.
         build.setProgress(100, 0, false);
         mNotifyManager.notify(id, build.build());
      }

      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
         // Update progress
         build.setProgress(100, values[0], false);
         mNotifyManager.notify(id, build.build());
         super.onProgressUpdate(values);
      }

      @Override
      protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //.........

                    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(rootFile,
                            arg0[1]));

                    InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int len1 = 0;
                    float conLen = c.getContentLength();
                    float total = 0;
                    while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                        total += len1;
                        publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / conLen));
                    }
                    f.close();

         return result;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
         super.onPostExecute(result);
         Log.e(TAG,"in PostExecute");
         build.setContentText("Download complete");
         // Removes the progress bar
         build.setProgress(0, 0, false);
         mNotifyManager.notify(id, build.build());
      }
   }

}
```

**Problem**

Every Think Working Fine But When I am in **postExecute Notification not update**

Any one gets Where I am going wrong ?

Comment: This is what written in android docs for updating notifications.`Caution: Android applies a rate limit when updating a notification. If you post updates to a notification too frequently (many in less than one second), the system might drop some updates.` You are updating notification multiple times in your progress update. That might be the issue.

Comment: any solution to avoid this issue @VivekMishra

Comment: I tink you can remove your notification from progress update method

Comment: then how to show download process in notification ? @VivekMishra

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871515/progress-bar-in-notification-bar-when-uploading-image

Comment: @VivekMishra its not updating but in postExecute i will cancle the notification and angain showing notification with complete lable done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks All Who Help Me I solve it Yesterday**

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
     super.onPostExecute(result);
     DownloadDone();
  }
```

**First I am Cancle My Notification Then Showing Again**

```
public void DonwloadDone()
        {
            mNotifyManager.cancel(id);
            mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            build = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());
            build.setContentTitle("Download")
                    .setContentText("Complete")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
            Notification notification = build.build();
            mNotifyManager.notify(id, notification);
            sendMyBroadCast("Complete",fx.getPath());

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code it looks like you are using same ids for different notifications so the first notification in `onPreExecute()` will be showing but the one in `onPostExecute()` might not show up.

Comment: i am using same id sir i miss that in question sorry for miss understanding

Comment: if you want to use same id, you need to call cancel before notify again. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965263/android-notification-update-for-same-notification-id

Comment: If you will cancel then it will be new notification everytime.

Comment: i want to update notification i down't wan't to cancle it

Comment: shouldn't this be  `build.setProgress(100, 0, false);`? do you want to hide progress after download?

Comment: can you try `build.setContentText("Download complete").setProgress(0, 0, false);`

Comment: @nightfury101 then what is the `diffrent build.setContentText("Download complete").setProgress(0, 0, false);` and `build.setContentText("Download complete");
         build.setProgress(0, 0, false);`

Comment: second build statment might be over writing the first. just in case.